# A word/phrase opposite in meaning to "fait accompli"

Tags: word-choice, antonyms

What is the word or phrase opposite in meaning to ***fait accompli***. For your reference the meaning is given below. I would prefer a foreign word but any can do.

> ***fait accompli***
>   
> French fɛt akɔ̃pli/
>   noun
>   a thing that has already happened or been decided before those affected hear about it, leaving them with no option but to accept it.
>   "the results were presented to shareholders as a *fait accompli*"

I want the word to be used in a particular context for instance an event that many people are glad has happened, many wish a different event to replace it. Like an event in the past that has bittersweet memories associated with it.

Comment: You need to tell us whether you want a non-decision or an adequately discussed decision or something else entirely.

Comment: I have edited the question and hope it helps

Comment: I don't really understand how what you want is an *opposite* to "fait accompli".  A fait accompli is simply "something already done".  What is the opposite of that?  A thing that has not happened?  A thing that has happened, but people don't have to accept?

Comment: a [disenchantment](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/disenchantment) or one of its synonymns; a rude awakening, a letdown.

Comment: I've closevoted as Unclear, but I would also add that I don't think ELL is a suitable site for questions that include the caveat *I would prefer a foreign word*.

Comment: I took that request to mean an English word borrowed from a foreign language that is still widely used in its indigenous language.

Comment: Yes User1 is right, By foreign word I meant an English word borrowed from a foreign language

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "a way to say that something is not yet decided when those who will be affected by the decision hear about it":

It is "still on the table".  The decision has not yet been made but the matter is being discussed and it is likely to be decided.

P.S. I don't understand what you mean by "bittersweet memories" in the context of *fait accompli*.

Comment: by bittersweet memories I mean for some people that consider the event bad has bitter memory of it while those that wanted that even to take place, for them it's good and sweet memory?